# pdfbox - add visual signature. COSObject cast error

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdf-generation, digital-signature, pdfbox

In `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.SignatureOptions`  have `setVisualSignature` method. I can create a visual signature from some other pdf stream that has a visual signature appearance (to copy the appearance).

1) I created a signature appearance pdf, and using the `setVisualSignature()` method, I manage to copy the visual signature. **Everything works;**

2) I change the visual signature (change image) from PDFBox. To get COSObject:

```
Iterator<Entry<COSObjectKey, Long>> xrefEntriesIt = doc.getDocument()
        .getXrefTable().entrySet().iterator();
while (xrefEntriesIt.hasNext()) {
    COSObject object = doc.getDocument().getObjectFromPool(
            xrefEntriesIt.next().getKey());
    if (object.getDictionaryObject(COSName.SUBTYPE) == COSName.IMAGE) {
        changeImage(object, doc);
    }
}
```

and to change Image:

```
private static void changeImage(COSObject obj, PDDocument doc) {

    PDXObjectImage imageInPdf =
        (PDXObjectImage) PDXObject.createXObject((COSStream) obj.getObject());

    File inputFile = new File("/new_SIGNATURE_IMG.jpg");
    PDXObjectImage newImage = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream(inputFile));
    imageInPdf.getCOSStream().replaceWithStream(newImage.getCOSStream());
    doc.save("/new.pdf");
}
```

**Everything works.**

3) When I call `setVisualSignature()` method with the new pdf and with the new appearance image (that I change with my code), I have that error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary   at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.addSignature(PDDocument.java:474)

Thats [samples](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1IQEoiXFg3IbWl6Y1NiODd5am8/edit?usp=sharing)

What happens?  Do I change images incorrectly?

Comment: Better late than never, this will be fixed in 1.8.10, see PDFBOX-2767.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `template.pdf` and `CHANGED_TEMPLATE.pdf` is that the signature field dictionary in the former one contains its appearance streams dictionary as a direct object:

```
9 0 obj
<< [...] /AP<</N 8 0 R>>>>
endobj
```

while in the latter one the appearance streams dictionary is an indirect object only referenced from the signature field dictionary:

```
5 0 obj
<<
[...]
/AP 10 0 R
>>
[...]
10 0 obj
<<
/N 15 0 R
>>
```

This is perfectly ok, the PDF specification does not require it to be direct in general:

> **AP** dictionary *(Optional; PDF 1.2)* An appearance dictionary specifying how the annotation shall be presented visually on the page (see 12.5.5, “Appearance Streams”). Individual annotation handlers may ignore this entry and provide their own appearances.
>
> *(Table 164 in [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Unfortunately the code where the exception occurs, i.e. the `PDDocument` method addSignature` in line 474, looks like this:

```
PDAppearanceDictionary ap = 
    new PDAppearanceDictionary((COSDictionary)cosBaseDict.getItem(COSName.AP));
```

Thus, PDFBox here expects the **/AP** value to be a direct dictionary object, not some reference to an indirect dictionary object.

I assume your first manipulation makes PDFBox rewrite the PDF in a way it assumes to be best (which seems to include making dictionaries indirect objects), and then PDFBox has other expectations...

If you made your first manipulation as an incremental update instead of a complete rewrite, PDFBox might leave the appearances dictionary untouched.